# What is the best option to thread in a spider?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-crawler

I wrote a spidering script in Python that works just fine. However, it takes a very long time to finish (upwards of 9 hours, depending on how many links the site has).

I want to implement threading in it to make it take less time, but i'm having trouble figuring out which part is the best to thread. At first glance I would create threads to go grab the page contents for each page, then lock the `visited_urls` and the `to_visit_urls` arrays to make sure everything's working with the same lists.

But it seems like it's probably spending the most time checking for duplicates in the `visited_urls` and `to_visit_urls` arrays, so would threading in this manner actually save me that much time? Is there a better way to thread my spider?

Comment: if you've profiled your code and are spending that much time on membership checks, perhaps you're using a `list` for `visited_urls` and `to_visit_urls` which has O(n) lookups. Try using a `set` instead, which has O(1) lookups.

Comment: I haven't profiled my code, i just have a _feeling_. :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use grequests, it's an asynchronous version of requests that allows you to scrape multiple urls at once significantly improving your throughput. If you iterate through your urls and work on sub lists this will be very effective. As for duplicates, simply converting your list to a set and back will remove them as sets by nature don't support duplicates.

```
urls = [...]
reqs = [grequests.get(x) for x in urls]
resp = grequests.map(reqs)
```

https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests

Comment: I have a feeling that conversion to a `set` takes O(n^2) to remove all the duplicates, does it not? That's much less efficient than the O(n) i currently take to guarantee the item i'm about to add doesn't exist. I don't know for sure though, and can't find that information anywhere...

Comment: "... doesn't **already** exist **in the list**," is what i meant to say.

Comment: are you certain that your bottleneck isn't network throughput? I'd be really surprised if your network speeds were faster than your calculations. Also why are you using two lists instead of just iterating over one? Also, if you did the set conversion once at startup then iterated over the results I doubt you would see a significant performance hit.

Comment: That's a good point, i could just use sets from the beginning instead of lists. And network throughput is very likely the largest bottleneck... I'm just trying to speed up the other areas if i can. I'm using two lists because one keeps track of the URLs it visited and one keeps track of the URLs it has yet to visit. Both are important, i'm not sure i know how to do a full spider of a site without keeping track of both of these data.

Comment: why do you need to keep track of the ones you haven't been too? iterating over a thing gaurantees that you interact with every element.

Comment: Because there are multiple links on every page, and those same links may also be on the pages the links lead to (think of like a header or a sidebar menu). I don't want to go to the same page more than once, that's a waste of time and could introduce loops.

Comment: convert it to a set, you can iterate over that or convert it back to a list. But there is no way that will be more time consuming than network latency. then you don't need some convoluted structure with two lists either